# PHP Variables in an SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm using session variables in an SQL query that updates either wins or losses whenever called. I've looked over similar questions, but they are using mysql as opposed to mysqli. What is the correct manner for using php variables in a mysqli query?
Here's what mine looks like:

```
$sqlQuery = "UPDATE users SET wins=wins+1 WHERE username == $_SESSION['username']";}
```

Comment: comparisons in SQL where clauses use 1 equals sign. Also, wrap variables in your string with curly braces. Especially arrays. Or else you will get an error in this case.

Comment: *"What is the correct manner for using php variables in a mysqli query?"* - It doesn't matter which MySQL API you use, your query itself is incorrect.

Comment: Since you seem to be using mysqli, then add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` and you'll see the error. Make sure you've also started the session.

Answer (score -1):

the resulting sql query should look like this:

`UPDATE users SET wins=wins+1 WHERE username = 'user_name';`

so we need to prepare it correctly:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "UPDATE users SET wins=wins+1 WHERE username = '%s';",
    $_SESSION['username']
);
```

but please, use a proper database connector (PDO, mysqli) and escape the username.